# Serial Port read write

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I am working on a project in which I have to send data to a controller device and get the respond from it. It works with RS232 protocol.
1st. To send data to the controller need an end character (semicolon ;) for example:

`?PA;?IA;?S;` to send these 3 commands

2nd. The controller answers on the above command with `PA=123;I=234;S=0;` also with the same end character (semicolon at the end of each command).

My problem is that I want to split the answers (receive Data) of the controller in 2 files the data which I am sending continuously with a Timer event and the data I am sending with a button event.

How can I make a function that makes these split.

Here is the code I am using so far:

I have created a class which I use to make the connection with the controller and the Data Received

```
Public Class SerialController
     Public Event DataReceived(sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs)

     Private Sub sPort_DataReceived(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles sPort.DataReceived
        Try
            Dim c As Char = ";"

            If sPort.BytesToRead = 0 Then Exit Sub

            Dim bytsToRead As Integer = sPort.BytesToRead
            '  MessageBox.Show(bytsToRead.ToString)
            Dim buf(bytsToRead - 1) As Byte

            bytsToRead = sPort.Read(buf, 0, bytsToRead)

            Threading.Monitor.Enter(rcvQLock)
            Try
                rcvQ.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf))

            Finally
                Threading.Monitor.Exit(rcvQLock)
            End Try

            While rcvQ.ToString.Contains(c)

                Dim l As Integer = rcvQ.ToString.IndexOf(c)

                Dim ca(l + 1) As Char

                Threading.Monitor.Enter(rcvQLock)
                Try
                    rcvQ.CopyTo(0, ca, 0, l + 1)
                    'MessageBox.Show(ca)
                    rcvQ.Remove(0, l + 1)
                Finally
                    Threading.Monitor.Exit(rcvQLock)
                End Try
                RaiseEvent DataReceived(Me, New DataReceivedEventArgs With {.Data = New String(ca)})
            End While
        Catch

        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

and in the main UI

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

    Private serialDataInputs As New List(Of SerialController)
    Dim sc As SerialController
    Dim parameter As String
    Dim AdHocState as inteeger

    Private Sub Form1_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
        For Each sc As SerialController In serialDataInputs
            sc.CloseSerialPort()
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim strComPort As String = "COM16"
        sc = New SerialController(strComPort)
        AddHandler sc.DataReceived, AddressOf sc_DataReceived

        sc.OpenSerialPort(strComPort, 115200, IO.Ports.Parity.None)

        Timer1.Enabled = True

    End Sub
    Private Sub sc_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs)


            Try

                AddOutput("Recieving<---" & e.Data)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
            End Try

        End If

    End Sub
    Private Delegate Sub TextDelegate(s As String)
    Private Sub AddOutput(s As String)

        If ListBox2.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim d As New TextDelegate(AddressOf AddOutput)
            ListBox2.Invoke(d, {s})
        Else
            ListBox2.Items.Add(s)

        End If

    End Sub



    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

      AdHocState = 1

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If AdHocState = 0 Then

            'sc.WriteData("?PA;?IA;?OA;")
            sc.WritePort("?PA;")
        ElseIf AdHocState = 1 Then  'the user wants to send a string to the device
            AdHocState = 2   'Flag that we expect a response to the user string

            sc.WritePort(TextBox1.Text)
        End If

        AdHocState = 0


    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You have explained what you want to achieve, but not what part of your code isn't working as expected. Could you edit your question to include this information? please explain what output you expect and what's actually happening, also include any error messages you get and what line they occur on.

Comment: All data are being saved at the moment  into a Listobox2. I want to create a function that saves the data that coming after Button 1 Click in a text file1 and the data after Timer_tick in another text file2

Comment: Have a look [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/drives-directories-files/how-to-write-text-to-files-with-a-streamwriter) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog?view=netframework-4.8) and give it a go.

Comment: thnx a lot for your response . i will have a look